# Configuring Asus USB-N13 Wireless Driver without Internet Connection

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, asus, usb-modem

I don't have a wired internet connection on my desktop and I had a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS right now.

I bought an ASUS USB-N13 Wireless Adapter; but although it recognizes my wireless network, it does not connect it somehow. It just gets in a loop when I try to connect. But it does not establish the connection.

How can I find the proper driver and install it WITHOUT internet connection on my desktop? Thank you community. I'm pretty a newbie on Linux so please consider it a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://tuxstack.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/install-drivers-for-wifi-usb-adapters-trendnet-tew-624ub-tp-link-wn821n-asus-edimax-etc-on-linux/

The asus n13 uses the powerful rtl8192cu chipset which apparently has crappy linux support.
The problem is solved by using a modded version of the old driver and injecting it into the kernel. 
Thanks to janez troha.